# Running a script for many files of the same extension. Getting 'UnboundLocalError'

Tags: python, glob

I'm trying to write a script to extract data from a number of files in a directory with the extension ".tp6" - ultimately I'm going to write them to a csv with the their associated filenames but I'm not focused on that now.

The code below works for ~50 files and then abruptly gets an 'UnboundLocalError' that reads:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "finder5.py", line 22, in module
> >
> > > uncovext(file)
> >
> > File "finder5.py", line 17, in uncovext
> >
> > > print ('%.3f' % outfloat)
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'outfloat' referenced before assignment.

Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFileDialog
import os
import glob

#defines the working directory
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
dir_path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
os.chdir(dir_path)

def uncovext(file1):
    for line in open(file1, 'r'):
        if line.startswith(' UNCONVOLVED INTEGRATED RADIANCE'):
            out = line[36:47]
            outfloat = (float(out) * 10000)
    print('%.3f' % outfloat)
    print(file)

#for each file with ext ".tp6"
for file in glob.glob("*.tp6"):
    uncovext(file)
```

Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: Hint: What'll happen when none of lines in file matches your condition?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you sometimes process a file that does not have a line starting with `UNCONVOLVED INTEGRATED RADIANCE`. The `outfloat` variable never gets bound, and so when the for loop in `uncovext` terminates, your print statements fail since a referenced variable is unavailable. The following code should show how to fix the problem.

```
import glob
import os
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog


def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    dir_path = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
    os.chdir(dir_path)
    for file_path in glob.glob('*.tp6'):
        uncovext(file_path)


def uncovext(file_path):
    for line in open(file_path):
        if line.startswith(' UNCONVOLVED INTEGRATED RADIANCE'):
            text = line[36:47]
            number = float(text) * 10000
            print('%.3f' % number)
            print(file_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```